# Meteor: How to subscribe to different publications for different templates on the same page?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have two templates that I'd like to render on the same page. One is a template that lists recent items; the other one lists items that are $text search results.

Data for each template is from a separate subscription. The problem is, minimongo doesn't support $text search, so I can't use $text to limit results from the client once the subscriptions are returned. That's a problem because both subscriptions are mixed together at the client side, so both my search results and recent items results look weird, because they each draw from both subscriptions.

I'm attempting to deal with it by using Iron Router to specify which template subscribes to which publication. However, my code doesn't work.

1. on the server, the file app.js, two separate publications:

   ```
   if (Meteor.isServer) {


   Meteor.publish("myitems", function () {
       return Items.find();
   });

   Items._ensureIndex({
       "itemName": "text",
       //"tags" : "text"
   });


   Meteor.publish("search", function (searchValue) {
       if (!this.userId) {
           this.ready();
           return;
       }
       return Items.find(
           {
               createdBy: this.userId,
               $text: {$search: searchValue},
               retired: {$ne: true}
           },
           {

               fields: {
                   score: {$meta: "textScore"}
               },
               sort: {
                   score: {$meta: "textScore"}
               }
           }
       );
   });


   }
   ```
2. client side code:

   - helper for the recent items template:

     ```
     Template.myitems.helpers(
     {
         items: function () {

             var d = new Date();
             var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
             return Items.find(
                 {
                     createdBy: currentUser,
                     createdAt: {
                         $gte: new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 30))
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     sort: {
                         createdAt: -1
                     },
                     limit: 5
                 });
         }
     ```

     });
   - helper for the search results template:

     Template.searchResults.helpers({
         searchitems: function () {
             if (Session.get("searchValue")) {
                 return Items.find({
                 }, {
                     sort: {"score": -1, "itemName": -1},
                     //limit: 10
                 });
             } else {
                 //return Items.find({});
             }
         }
     });
     }
   - onCreated subscription for each template, separately:

     ```
     Template.myitems.onCreated (function () {

         Meteor.subscribe('myitems');
     });

     Template.searchResults.onCreated (function () {

         Meteor.subscribe('search');

     });
     ```
3. Router controller configuration: yes you'll see that it attempts to subscribe as well, but it fails anyway, so there's no duplicate subscription to "myitems"

   ```
   itemsController = RouteController.extend({
       //waitOn: function() {
       //    return [
       //        Meteor.subscribe('myitems')
       //    ];
       //},
       //data: function() {
       //    //return { items : Items.find({}), item_id : this.params._id }
       //    return {items: Items.find()};
       //},
       action: function() {
           this.render('items');
           this.render('searchitems', {to: 'region1'});
           this.render('myitems', {
               to: 'region3',
               waitOn: function() {
                   return [
                       Meteor.subscribe('myitems')
                   ];
               },
               data: function(){

                   return {items: Items.find()};
               }
           });

       }
   });
   ```

The above iron router code doesn't attempt to subscribe to the search publication. It attempts to subscribe to the recent items ('myitems') publication, but somehow the returned "items" is empty. The issue is not due to any wrong setting in the publication, because the commented out code works: if it were uncommented, then "items" do get returned and isn't empty, even if I don't use onCreated to subscribe to it.

My questions are:

1. what's wrong with the above code? I know that the subscription to "myitems" fail from the Iron Router. The subscription to "myitems" succeeds in the "onCreate", but the search results also draws from "myitems", instead of drawing from "searchResults" only.
2. assuming I can fix the above code, is Iron Router the way to go to solve my original problem: the search results subscription and the recent items subscription need to be separate, although the two templates are to be rendered on the same webpage?

Comment: You probably just need to move the subscriptions out of IronRouter into the two templates. If you put the subscriptions into the onCreated function of the relevant template, then you already have the separation that you wanted.

Comment: @mwarren Simply putting the subscription into onCreated doesn't work. For one, the search subscription needs to change every time a new search query is entered. Did you mean putting the subscription into onCreated and adding some other tricks too?

Comment: The subscription shouldn't need renewing every time. It should just need setting once for a template. It's a kind of permission, not a kind of query. Queries can work within the subscription you've set for the template.

Comment: @mwarren I still don't have the separation of the subscriptions... it appears that my search query returns all recent items as results, whether the text matches or not.

Comment: You haven't shown much code, I don't know what you are referring to. Where's the search query? Where are the '$text search results'?

Comment: @mwarren I've updated the post. Thanks!